# Which files or commits does Git consider when calculating differences for cherry-pick, merge and rebase?

Tags: git, version-control, internals

I've read about the Git internals [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Branches-in-a-Nutshell) and [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects) and know what a commit is, as well as a tree and a blob.

I know that Git stores individual files instead of file differences (deltas), and that the later ones are calculated in real time as necessary. The documentation also speaks often about the "difference between two commits" (whether they are parent and child, ancestor/descendant or neither of them).

However, it's not clear to me how Git calculates those deltas in various situations (cherry-picking, merge, rebase). And which files (i.e. files from which commit) are considered in each case?

I've read that according to that structure a single commit can be considered a whole branch (i.e. the commit history leading up to that commit) in the sense that for a given file I can reach all of its versions by traversing the branch back (though not necessarily back to its root I suppose; just back to a immediately previous file version may be enough). If my assumption is wrong, please clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rules are simple enough conceptually but get complicated in practice.

- A real `git merge` uses the commit DAG to find the merge base(s).  The merge base is defined as the Lowest Common Ancestor (generalized in the obvious way to arbitrary DAGs where there may be multiple LCAs, vs simple trees where there's always a unique LCA).  The `git merge-base` command will, given two commits, find a (default) or all (`--all`) merge base commits from the DAG.

  If there are multiple merge bases, the algorithm depends on the `-s` (strategy) argument.  The default `recursive` strategy merges the merge-bases using recursion (what else? :-) ).  This is currently done the slow-simple-stupid way: if there are 5 merge bases, Git merges two of them (finding the merge base of those two as needed) and makes a "virtual commit" from the result, merges that result with the next (3rd) in the list-of-5, merges *that* result with the 4th, and merges *that* with the 5th to get the final virtual merge base.  (To make this all work correctly, I believe Git actually makes *real* commits.  There's no reason not to: these unreferenced commits will be garbage-collected automatically later.)

  The `resolve` strategy simply picks one of the multiple merge bases and uses that as the base.

  In any case, the two diffs that get combined, once we have a single merge base hash ID `$base` and the two branch-tips, are the output from:

  ```
  git diff $base $tip1
  git diff $base $tip2
  ```

  (more or less—there's some tweaking of the `--rename-limit` value if needed, depending on extra merge command arguments, and all this assumes no special merge drivers; the actual merging happens file-by-file, but the merge base *version* for each file comes from `$base`, with any rename detection happening first from the two commit-wide diffs).
- The `git cherry-pick` command diffs each commit against its parent, and then first tries to apply the resulting delta as a patch.  If that fails it falls back on "three way merge", but the merge base is on a file-by-file basis rather than a commit-by-commit basis, because it uses the `Index:` information in the formatted patch.  There's one `Index:` line per file-in-the-patch, giving the SHA-1 IDs of the two blobs in question.

  Thus, the merge base is initially ignored entirely: the cherry-pick just uses the patch as a patch.  Only if the patch does not apply (as in `git apply`) does the cherry-pick fall back to a three-way merge (as in `git apply -3`).  The blob itself must also exist in your repository—for a cherry-pick, it always does; for a literal `git apply` of an emailed patch, it may not.

  At this point the two diffs to be combined are:

  ```
  git diff $indexbase $file1
  the diff in the patch # equivalent to git diff $indexbase $file2
  ```

  where `$indexbase` is the file extracted by the hash ID in the `Index:` line and `$file1` is the file in your work-tree.  (This file matches the `HEAD` commit unless you're using `git cherry-pick -n`.)  In an arbitrary (emailed) patch you don't necessarily have `$file2` at all, just the diff; in a cherry-picked patch, `$file2` is the version of the file in the commit being cherry-picked (but it's not needed since we already have the diff!).

  If you cherry-pick a merge commit, you must tell Git *which* parent of that merge commit is to be used to produce a changeset-as-patch.  This step is completely manual.
- A rebase consists, functionally, of a series of cherry-pick operations.  Merge commits are omitted from rebases.  (Interactive rebase's `--preserve-merges` operation makes *new* merges, completely ignoring the original merge.)  An interactive rebase literally runs `git cherry-pick` (one at a time for each commit to be copied), while a non-interactive rebase attempts to use `git format-patch <args> | git am -3` if it can (format-patch elides "empty" commits so this is only possible without `-k`).

  The commits to be copied are chosen via an actual `git rev-list --cherry-pick` on a symmetric difference in some cases, or, for algorithmic purposes, something equivalent.

Comment: A very informed answer, although I'll have to remember some graph theory to fully absorb it (I was hopeful it could be described in simpler words). I'm going to accept it nevertheless.

Comment: It could be (I've done it in other answers), it just sounded like you knew these things and I could abbreviate. :-) The multiple LCAs only occur when you have criss-cross merges, and even then, the virtual merge base stuff often comes up with the same base tree as simply picking one of the two bases, so it's merely for precision in corner cases.

Comment: I don't think that git-cherry-pick uses (or at least, I don't think it defaults to) a diff + patch application.  I think that it (at least by default) uses a three-way merge mechanism (but with a variation, so that the commit to be cherry-picked immediate parent acts as the common ancestor).  (Trivia: revert works in a similar mechanism, but with ever stranger selections for the ancestor/ours/theirs sides going into the three-way merge.)

Comment: @EdwardThomson: it definitely used to, although I saw a bunch of stuff inside it changed since maybe Git 2.3 or so, when I last looked closely.  You could be right, but I remember spending some time finding the code that literally extracted the "Index:" lines...

Comment: @EdwardThomson: BTW, the reason, as far as I could tell, for doing it that way was that revert could then share the code with cherry-pick, since the blob hashes in the Index line point to the desired base version. If you think about it, using the blob's index means that you get the "merge base" from a reasonably appropriate commit: even if that's very far back in history, or relatively recent, it all just works.

Comment: @torek Ugh, I forget all the details, but _rebase_ definitely still does the patch creation and application dance (at least by default, it uses `git-rebase--am`) but cherry-pick and revert do share code but should both use the merge mechanisms directly.  https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/sequencer.c#L580  I only happen to know this because I stole the ideas for cherry-pick and revert in libgit2.  ;)

Comment: Ah, that's the code that was new, the last time I looked at it (not sure when, some git 2.x era). That does indeed seem to just run a straight recursive merge by default, with the base version being the cherry-picked version's parent. How this works when cherry-picking a *range* of commits could be especially interesting, and it might be worth devising some test commits to expose corner case behaviors.